# Simple PDE question

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I was trying to solve the problem 2.5.15 (Evans) from this notes:

http://www.math.umn.edu/~robt/docs/evans_solutions.pdf

But, in page 12, line 11, I really dont know how to prove that

\begin{align*}
& \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{t-\delta}^{t}\frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}g(s)ds\\
&\quad +\lim_{x \rightarrow
0^{+}}\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{0}^{t-\delta}\frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}g(s)ds\\
&=g(t)\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{t-\delta}^{t}\frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}ds\\
\end{align*}

where $g(0) = 0$ and $\delta >0$ fixed. Please, I need help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the second term goes to zero as $x\to 0$ because the limits of the integral are bounded away from $t$ so that the integral is always finite. As for the first term: $\displaystyle|\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{t-\delta}^{t}\frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}[g(s)-g(t)]ds|=|\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{t-\delta}^{t-\epsilon}\frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}[g(s)-g(t)]ds+\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{t-\epsilon}^{t}\frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}[g(s)-g(t)]ds|=|\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{t-\epsilon}^{t}\frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}[g(s)-g(t)]ds|\le\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{t-\epsilon}^{t}\frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}ds\cdot\sup\limits_{s\in[t-\epsilon,t]}|g(s)-g(t)|.$

So as long as $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{t-\epsilon}^{t}\frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}ds$ is finite for all $\epsilon>0$, we can take $\epsilon\to 0$ and since $g$ is continuous, $\sup\limits_{s\in[t-\epsilon,t]}|g(s)-g(t)|\to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, giving the result. And they prove that the  integral is finite in the next step.